# How to fix service worker red dot error without unregistering it?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker

[image]

I've observed that when I make changes to a service worker, it occasionally displays as a red dot.

I tried refreshing the browser, but the red dot remained; the only way to remove it is to unregister it.

I'm quite sure my service worker is alright because reinstalling the service worker removes the red dot.

What is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

That means the Service Worker is installed and waiting, but not yet active. All new service workers pass through phases: `installing` => `waiting` => `active`.  Explicit activation is required for modified/updated service workers to avoid unexpected behaviors while the browser is running the app.  Try `skipWaiting()`:

```
// service-worker.js

self.addEventListener('install', e => {
  self.skipWaiting() // always activate updated SW immediately
})
```

Comment: But there is no skipWaiting indicator in console, if the service worker is waiting, it should be appeared as waiting state below current one, but notice my screenshot, there is no one waiting.

Comment: Good point.  Is the SW `install` event being fired?

Comment: I didn't subscribe to the 'install' event in my service worker, but the firebase SDK service worker did subscribe to the 'install' event, but the entire firebase codebase lacks the `skipWaiting` keyword, which confuses me because the firebase service worker skips the waiting state every time I update it.